# What is the difference between boomset and headset?

Tags: airbus-a320, headset

Both "boomset" and "headset" are terms used e.g. by Airbus:

> The audio management system includes:
>
> - [...] sockets at each station
>
>   - **headset** jack and **boomset** connector (hand microphone connector) for pilot, copilot and third occupant
>   - **headset** jack for fourth occupant
> - [...] **boomsets** for the pilot, copilot, and third occupant, and three hand microphones (fourth) [...]

<sup>([Airbus A320 FCOM - Communications - General - Audio Management System](https://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/A320-Communications.pdf), emphasis mine)</sup>

What's the main difference between these two things or are they the same?

Comment: Can you give us the context and where you heard "boomset"?  Because I have never heard this word used...

Comment: @Biafable, thanks. That's just the sort of reference and contextual information I would expect an OP to include in a "good" question. Hence my comment. (BTW, the term is found on the eighth page of the PDF file - which is labeled Page 1 of the Comm section in the document itself.  In case it saves anyone else hunting around...)

Comment: I'm not sure about this context, but a boomset may be a mic/headphone combo that covers a single ear (like you would see phone operators wearing), whereas headset covers both.

Comment: Or even, just a boom mic... listen to the speaker, push to transmit on the yoke, voice picked up with a boom mic. Dunno, as I'd never come across the term before either, but I'll offer this as a guess.

Comment: @RonBeyer that was my guess.

Comment: "Shake your boomset" does not mean to lift up your headset in your hand and give it a shake--